# Does a reflecting object move faster than one that does not reflect?

Tags: energy, velocity, reflection, absorption

Suppose you have two objects with the same mass and shape, such as a ball, and the only difference between the two is that one reflects light and the other does not. Would one object's velocity be some greater than the other?

Do to the absorption and reflection of light on the objects and one reflecting light and the other absorbing light in a I vacuum such as outer space .In my mind, the reflecting object would move faster due to the fact it is not absorbing the photon energy from the light, but redirecting it. I would imagine it somehow as an object covered with oil and moving through water. The other object would move more slowly due to absorption of some of the energy, one being energy and the other exergy.  If I am mistaken, please tell me.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include *why* you think the reflective property matters in the motion of an object?

Comment: i tried to edit it better for you.

Comment: @KyleKanos: I think (s)he is asking if radiation pressure will slow objects.

Comment: If they exist near some powerful source of light, then **yes**. A solar sail is a hypothetical giant mirror, which uses this reflection to accelerate outwards our solar system. But why is it a quantum-field-theory question?

Comment: @JerrySchirmer: I suspected as much, but the qft tag and the phrasing of the initial question was throwing me off a little.

Comment: i also was asking this because every space ship or ufo seems to have reflection property's. and just wanted to know if there was a reason.

Comment: it made me put a tag and i just clicked that one because it wouldnt let me tag it as just a theory

Comment: @Longlost13 quantum-field-theory has nothing to do with your question. I switched the tag for you to 'reflection'. Take a look at my answer above.

Comment: yes the reason i asked this question was to see if in space would you use a ship that mirror's light or one that does not. because i am creating a design for a craft in my mind.

Comment: As you can see, it depends on which way you are going. You would probably want your solar sale to be easily packed when going towards the source of light.

Comment: @Longlost13: the mirror is better, because it reverses the momentum of the light, rather than merely absorbing it.

Comment: shape wise smooth or golf ball like? cause wouldnt the golf ball surface reflect better than the other. and i also heard that a evenly dented object has a higher velocity then a smooth. i think myth busters but said this but cant go off of tv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reflective object will slow down more than an absorbent or transparent one if the light is coming from in front.

A reflective object will speed up more than an absorbent or transparent one if the light is coming from behind.

Momentum conservation is the reason in both cases, light carries momentum, to reverse from reflection means it delivers almost twice the momentum it came in with.

Comment: yes, it is 2p but it has to be taken out of the incoming energy

Answer (score 2):

This [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nprjUFRFfEA)  shows beads being pushed by a laser beam.

The photons that compose the light beam have momentum and hitting the beads transfer the momentum to the beads. Thus, if the beads are completely absorbent momentum conservation says that they will move faster than if less absorbent.

Let us analyze the case when a photon hits vertically a perfect mirror .

[A classical ball](https://www.teachengineering.org/view_activity.php?url=collection/cub_/activities/cub_energy/cub_energy_lesson03_activity3.xml) with momentum p would bounce back  elastically. The momentum contributed by the ball coming and going would be zero if it were not for momentum conservation, since the incoming momentum is p. This means that the large mass of the mirror (M*v=P) will have to move slightly to the value of P=2p, so some energy will have to be given up by the ball. The return ball will have a momentum slightly smaller than p  to obey energy conservation.

[image: bouncing balls]

> Figure 1. The illustration of the percentage of energy returned to a ball after one bounce (or, the "range of bounciness" of each ball).

In the classical case the elasticity of the collision is taken into account.

A photon loses momentum only if its frequency is lowered, so there will be a [Doppler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect) shift to lower frequencies, the amount dependent on the specific reaction :photon-mirror, the mass of the mirror the lattices etc.

In this case  the momentum given up by each photon is p, but energy is converted due to extra momentum  due to momentum conservation. It is a better case than absorption even if reflection is not perfect, because the target is not heated up.

So in the video it must be that the kick given by reflected photons is moving the beads.

In conclusion hitting an object with a light beam transfers  momentum  and energy from  the photons of the beam to the object.

p.s. an edit was made to correct for wrong momentum conservation! as shown in Timeus answer.